# What is the algorithm to produce every k-bit number?

Tags: algorithm

I want an algorithm to do the following: When the input is for example 3 I want every 3-bit number to be produced like the following:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for all your answers, But I'd prefer an algorithm that treats '1's and '0's as characters and the whole answer as an string so I could extend the answer for characters as well. Like producing every possible combination of `a,b,c` with the length of 3.

Comment: is this homework? (tag it if it is)

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all binary combinations for a number in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463372/list-of-all-binary-combinations-for-a-number-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

A straight-forward algorithm would be:

- calculate `2^n-1`; in your case, `7`.
- `for i = 0 : 7` convert `i` to binary form
- output binary form

Answer (score 1):

It means every number between zero and 2^n-1 which n is your bit number

Comment: Yeah and in math my statement is correct, I mean I didn't said between 0 and 2**n including 2**n

Comment: But wouldn't that also mean you're leaving out 0? Because you also didn't say including 0... :P

Comment: Yes you are right, but that details is easily deductable, that's why I missed that parts, nontheless you're right

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code which should help you :

```
function listNumbers (bits : Int) : List<String> {
  l = [];
  if (bits == 0) {
    l.append("");        
  } else {
    prev = listNumbers(bits-1);
    for (number in prev) {
      l.append("0" + number);
      l.append("1" + number);
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a recursive algorithm. This is written in Java:

```
public void printBin(String soFar, int iterations) {
    if(iterations == 0) {
        System.out.println(soFar);
    }
    else {
        printBin(soFar + "0", iterations - 1);
        printBin(soFar + "1", iterations - 1);
    }
}
```

You would execute this like this:

```
printBin("", 3);
```

That would give you all possible binary numbers with 3 digits.

Note, however, that with really big amounts of digits, you might get overflows.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

What you want do do is [generate combinations](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/generating-combinations-1/) the code in the article shouldn't be too hard to generalize for all characters using modular arithmetic. Or alternately you map characters onto numeric values, calculate the permutations and then map back to characters.